# TS Compiler API : Traverse through all custom defined properties of a given type

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

For the following model structure,

```
interface Address{
   country: string;
}

interface Author{
  authorId: number;
  authorName:string;
  address: Address;
}

interface Book{
  bookId:string;
  title: string;
  author : Author;
}
```

I am trying to traverse through all of the properties of Book interface.

```
const bookType = // get the type node of Book
const stack: any[] = [...bookType.getProperties()];
const props: any[] = [];

while (stack.length) {
  const prop = stack.pop();
  props.push(prop);
  if (checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(prop, node)) { //node is a ts.MethodDeclaration which returns a value of type Book
    stack.push(...checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(prop, node).getProperties());
  }
}
```

The above code works but it also reads the properties of in built types like string, number etc., ( toLocaleString, valueOf, toPrecision). I would like to extract the properties of custom types/interfaces and ignore the in built types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above code works but it also reads the properties of in built types like string, number etc., ( toLocaleString, valueOf, toPrecision). I would like to extract the properties of custom types/interfaces and ignore the in built types.

This can be achieved by going from the type, to the symbol, then checking if the symbol links back to any declarations found in your project. For example:

```
// untested, but something along these lines
const type = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(prop, node);
const isTypeInYourPoject = type.getSymbol()?.getDeclarations()?.some(d => {
  // Or you could check the file path is not
  // in the `node_modules/typescript/lib` folder.
  return isFilePathInYourProject(d.getSourceFile().fileName);
});

if (isTypeInYourPoject) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

You can also look at stuff like `type.flags` to tell if it's a type like `string` or `number`.